# How do I compute the difference of two queries?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, set-difference

I have a MongoDB collection that contains a set of documents. Each document has an ISODate `date` and an integer `id` (not `_id`). `id: X` is said to *exist* for `date: D` if there is a document in the collection with field values `{ id: X, date: D }`. So, for example:

```
{ id: 1, date: 1/1/2000 }
{ id: 1, date: 1/2/2000 }
{ id: 1, date: 1/3/2000 }
{ id: 1, date: 1/4/2000 }
{ id: 2, date: 1/2/2000 }
{ id: 2, date: 1/3/2000 }
{ id: 3, date: 1/3/2000 }
```

I would like to track `id`s over time as they are created and destroyed day-to-day. Using the above data, over the date range 1/1/2000 to 1/4/2000:

```
1/1/2000: id 1 is created
1/2/2000: id 2 is created
1/3/2000: id 3 is created
1/4/2000: id 2 is destroyed
1/4/2000: id 3 is destroyed
```

I think the best way to solve this would be to loop day by day, see what `id`s exist between today and the next day, and perform a set difference. For example, to get the set of ids created and destroyed on 1/2/2000, I need to perform two set differences between arrays for either day:

```
var A = [ <ids that exist on 1/1/2000> ];
var B = [ <ids that exist on 1/2/2000> ];
var created_set = set_difference(B, A); // Those in B and not in A
var destroyed_set = set_difference(A, B); // Those in A and not in B
```

I can use a `find()` command to get cursors for `A` and `B`, but I do not know how to perform the `set_difference` between two cursors.

My other option was to use an aggregation pipeline, but I cannot think about how to formulate the pipeline in such a way that I can use the `$setDifference` operator.

As a MongoDB novice, I am sure I'm thinking about the problem the wrong way. Surely this is something that can be done? What am I missing?

Comment: what exactly is your goal? find all changes that occurred between two dates? generate a list of all changed ever?

Comment: @jtmarmon My goal is to generate a list of creation and destroyed dates for each id number found in the collection. The second list of data above that shows when the various ids are created and destroyed is what I'm going after.

Comment: Is the date an ISODate format?

Comment: @chridam Yes, the date is an ISODate, I'll update the question with that detail.

Comment: Why aren't you simply solving this in client code, or when writing the updates, rather than on read? Doing this on read is a little against the MongoDB philosophy. What if those cursors are on different shards, on different continents or are terabytes in size?

Comment: @mnemosyn Well that's related to the end of my question. I'm not well versed in MongoDB, and see there is a lot of power available through the query and aggregation tools, but am not convinced that this problem is one that should be solved by either one. If you think this is something that's best solved on the client side, I'll take that to heart.

Comment: @fbrereto: I would never put this kind of complexity and business-logic in the database or in db-related code, I guess that is largely a philosophy question. I'm afraid the aggregation framework drags lots of people into using overly complex queries and overly complex data structures, instead of fixing the problem at its core, but opinions vary...

Comment: I would generally agree that the use of aggregation framework is often indicative of bad schema design, but hey sometimes you're stuck with what you're stuck with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.mystuff.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$id', created: {$first: '$date'}, destroyed: {$last: '$date'}}}
])
```

Comment: Good Lord, that's amazing.

Comment: @mnemosyn That may be true, however for my purposes `id` will exist in exactly one contiguous block of dates.

Comment: @mnemosyn out of curiousity can you give an example & a reason why this wouldn't work with gaps

Comment: @jtmarmon: well, it wouldn't find the gaps, only the first created and the last destroyed, i.e. it can't find `A...B, C...D, E...F`, but it would only find `A...F` (naturally, since you'd need something that can output a list of date pairs for each id). But apparently, that is not what the OP was looking for, and this is reasonably short and somewhat elegant...

Comment: ohhh i see. that's under the assumption that every date is an event - i was just assuming that the first = created and the last = destroyed. got it though, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following sample collection:

```
db.collection.insert([
    { id: 1, date: ISODate("2000-01-01") },
    { id: 1, date: ISODate("2000-01-02") },
    { id: 1, date: ISODate("2000-01-03") },
    { id: 1, date: ISODate("2000-01-04") },
    { id: 2, date: ISODate("2000-01-02") },
    { id: 2, date: ISODate("2000-01-03") },
    { id: 3, date: ISODate("2000-01-03") }
]);
```

The following aggregation will give you some direction towards what you are trying to achieve using the [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operator:

```
var start = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
var end = new Date(2000, 0, 2)
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match":{
            "date": {
                "$gte": start, 
                "$lte": end 
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$date",            
            "A": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$date", start ] },
                        "$id",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            },
            "B": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$date", end ] },
                        "$id",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "A": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$A", [false] ]
            },
            "B": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$B", [false] ]
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "date": "$_id",
            "created_set": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$B", "$A" ]
            },
            "destroyed_set": {
                "$setDifference": [ "$A", "$B" ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2000-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "created_set" : [2, 1],
            "destroyed_set" : []
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "created_set" : [],
            "destroyed_set" : [1]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for - the concise set of ids that are coming and going between two different dates.